# How to get JavaScript variable in AJAX call as Laravel route name

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, routes

Hi I am using one AJAX function for 7 API sync calls so that I tried this code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sync-commands" data-name="order-sync" >Shopify Order Sync</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sync-commands" data-name="shopify.order.sync">Shopify Product</a>
```

and in ajax call, I am using this code:

```
$('.sync-commands').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var route_name =$(this).attr("data-name");

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route(route_name)}}",  //error line here no route/undefine variable etc
```

How can I access this variable in my URL?
I just want to call only one ajax call of 10 calls for different routes.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the ajax call is inside a JS file and not in a script tag at the bottom of blade template. So from this, maybe it would be easier to use the `route` helper function in the blade template:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sync-commands" data-name="{{route('order-sync')}}">Shopify Order Sync</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sync-commands" data-name="{{route('shopify.order.sync')}}">Shopify Product</a>
```

This is then rendered as the full route, then your JS event will work with a slight change:

```
$('.sync-commands').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var route_name =$(this).attr("data-name");
    $.ajax({
        url: route_name,
```

Comment: thats also awsom.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner way to do it without using data tags by using a natural workaround of anchor tags and by using `preventDefault()` in your js file.

```
<a href="{{route('order-sync')}}" class="sync-commands" >Shopify Order Sync</a>
<a href="{{route('shopify.order.sync')}}" class="sync-commands">Shopify Product</a>
```

JS

```
$('.sync-commands').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
```

Comment: ok, that's great.
Will it reload the page or not in your condition?

Comment: @MuhammadAmirShahzad it won't refresh the page. `preventDefault()`  default action of the event won't trigger if you have this. You can check it from jquery docs here  https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/